# How to sync Chrome extensions' details?

Tags: google-chrome, sync, google-chrome-extensions

[Chrome Sync](https://chrome.google.com/sync) can sync extensions, browser settings, etc. I have enabled these sync settings:

[image: chrome___settings_syncSetup_advanced]

Each extension can sync its own settings using [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), however the **details** of each extension are necessarily not managed by the extension for security reasons, and these details do not sync to my devices. Here is an example:

[image: chrome___extensions_]

[image: chrome___extensions__ dark_reader]

I'd like to know how to sync these details like "Site access", "Allow in incognito", etc. for each extension. It is a royal pain to manually manage these—especially things like URL lists, which don't seem to be able to be bulk edited.

Note: Chrome policy management is out of scope in regard to answering this question.

Comment: This is an issue for Firefox too.